# How to parse code after it has been stripped of styles and elements in python

Tags: python, html

This is a very basic question regarding html parsing:

I am new to python(coding,computer science, etc), teaching myself to parse html and I have imported both pattern and beautiful soup modules to parse with. I found this code on the internet to cut out all formatting.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib
from lxml import etree
from pattern import web
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?f=html"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)


print(text)
```

This produces the following Output:

```
EUR/USD14265522866931.056661.056751.056081.057911.05686USD/JPY1426552286419121.405121.409121.313121.448121.382GBP/USD14265522866821.482291.482361.481941.483471.48281EUR/GBP14265522865290.712790.712900.712300.713460.71273USD/CHF14265522866361.008041.008291.006551.008791.00682EUR/JPY1426552286635128.284128.296128.203128.401128.280EUR/CHF14265522866551.065121.065441.063491.066281.06418USD/CAD14265522864891.278211.278321.276831.278531.27746AUD/USD14265522864960.762610.762690.761150.764690.76412GBP/JPY1426552286682179.957179.976179.854180.077179.988
```

now from this point how can I parse further to say If I only want the string 'USD/CHF' or a particular point of data?

Is there a easier method to  webscrape and parse with? Any suggestions would be great!

System Specs: 
windows 7 64bit
IDE: idle
python: 2.7.5

Thank you all in advance, 
Rusty

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses! they both worked.

So my next question to you all and community is that as a beginner in coding and computer science what are some fundamental things I should learn bc I feel like my knowledge is very sparse and I would like a bottom-up approach to learning, so I can give back on this message board.

Thanks,
Rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Find the cell *by text* (`USD/CHF`, for example) and get the [*following siblings*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings):

```
text = 'USD/CHF'
cell = soup.find('td', text=text)
for td in cell.next_siblings:
    print td.text
```

Prints:

```
1426561775912
1.00
768
1.00
782
1.00655
1.00879
1.00682
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the turn around and it most definitely worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, beautiful soup is pretty much as easy as it gets. I would write a regex to strip the number out after a string of characters. I hope this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something quick and dirty like this.  Obviously code like this will change based on the string itself.  More advanced ways would use python's regex library. But sometimes it's nice to keep it simple.

```
string = []
starting_position = text[text.find("USD/CHF")+7:] #+7 to start after the tag USD/CHF
for ch in starting_position:
    if ch.isdigit() == True or ch == ".":
        string.append(str(ch))
    else:
        break
print "".join(string)
```